# How to avoid overriding of styleClass defined in Jsf page

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2

```
<h:inputText id="emailText" styleClass="emailAddress" value="{bean.emailText}"/>
```

The style class `emailAddress` is getting overridden if we do any operation like:

```
$('emailText').addClass('error'); in jQuery
(HtmlInputText)input.setStyleClass('error') in bean
```

Can anyone tell me whether we can maintain both the style class even if we add or remove classes on the input text field.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163189/setstyleclass-method-is-overriding-the-already-defined-styleclass

Comment: @BalusC Can you please suggest something as it is very much needed. Thanks.

Comment: @BalusC May I know whether it's not a right question to answer? Thanks.

Comment: I'm generally less interested in answering problems with bad practices.

Comment: @BalusC It would be great if you tell me why it is a bad practice. Atleast in a very short note. Thanks.

Comment: answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163189/setstyleclass-method-is-overriding-the-already-defined-styleclass